# How to add a char into an already sized array?

Tags: c++

I have to write a function in C++ witch takes a word as a `char[]` input from the console and checks if the letters "u", "o", "i", "e", "a" exist in the `char[]`. And if these letter do exist in the array then it should add the letter "b" to the word and the output should look like this:

> pig → pibig, trash → trabash, egg → ebegg, inbox → ibinbobox

and I'm stuck. Thanks for helping.

```
void bLanguage(char inputString[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (inputString[i] != 0)  {
        counter++;
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
        if (inputString[j] ==('a') ||
            inputString[j] == ('e') ||
            inputString[j] == ('i') ||
            inputString[j] == ('o') ||
            inputString[j] == ('u')) {
        }
    }

    cout << inputString << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't.   The caller needs to ensure that the supplied `inputString` is long enough to accommodate both the input and any added characters.  Then, when adding, shuffle remaining data down - which is safe ONLY  if the supplied array is long enough to do that.

Comment: You have added `C++` tag, so code using C++ features like `std::string`. Using `char[]` in C++ code is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cout` characters of your string separately:

```
void bLanguage(char * inputString) {
    for (int i = 0; inputString[i] != 0; i++) {
        char c = inputString[i];
        if (c ==('a') ||
        c == ('e') ||
        c == ('i') ||
        c == ('o') ||
        c == ('u')) {
            cout << c << 'b' << c;
        } else {
            cout << c;
        }
    }
}
```